# Unable to find field "title" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm starting to make BDD with cucumber.

I have written my first scenario like this

```
Scenario: ...
Given I am on the new event page
And I fill in "title" with "tata"
```

With these steps

```
Given /^I am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit("/event/new")
end

When /^I fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field.gsub(' ', '_'), :with => value)
end
```

It works good, nice.
Now, I want to use the send function to visit a page. So I have changed the first step like this.

```
Given /^I am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  self.send("new_event_path".to_sym)
end
```

The page is found but the fill_in does not work because an element is not found.

```
 Unable to find field "title" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

I don't understand why it's not working with the send function?

Comment: Your second implementation of "I am on" doesn't visit anything, it just evaluates the URI and throws it away.

Comment: Add do you know a solution to be more generic than the first solution ? I have see this solution here : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels/blob/master/lib/generators/cucumber_rails_training_wheels/install/templates/support/paths.rb

Comment: ok, I just have to do a visit(path_to(my_page))

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

```
Given /^I am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
   visit(self.send("new_event_path".to_sym))
end
```

Thanks Dave, your response help me :)

Eric